# chef solo における database のエラー

Tags: mysql, chef, aws

【質問】

```
$ bundle exec knife solo cook ノード名
```

で以下の通りエラーが発生が出る

> Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_database[aws]'

*現状databaseを使わないレシピは動いています

【やりたいこと】
opscodeのdatabaseを使ってrecipeを書きたい
（次のレシピではデータベースを作成しようとしているだけです）
*公式
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/master/README.md

【レシピ】

### ./Berkshelf

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"
cookbook "mysql2_chef_gem"
cookbook "database"
cookbook "yum"
```

### node/ノード.jsonファイル

```
{
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[sample]"
  ],
  "automatic": {
    "ipaddress": "ノード名"
  }
}
```

### site-cookbooks/sample/metadata.rb

```
name             'sample'
maintainer       'YOUR_COMPANY_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures mysql'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'
depends 'database'
```

### site-cookbooks/sample/recipes/default.rb

```
mysql_connection_info = {
  :host     => '127.0.0.1',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => 'パスワード'
}
mysql_database "aws" do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  action :create
end
```

【環境】
Mac OSX 10.9.5
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.4.0
Chef: 12.0.3
Bundler version 1.7.11
database (4.0.2)
chefの流し込んでいる先はAmazon Linux(2014 9)です

【その他】
海外サイト等でもヒントになりそうな情報がありましたら
ご指摘頂ければと思います。

【エラー】

> mysql_database[aws] action create  ================================================================================
>   Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_database[aws]'  ================================================================================
>
> ### LoadError
>
> cannot load such file -- mysql2
>
> ### Cookbook Trace:
>
> /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:103:in `test_client'
>
>   /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:37:in`block in '
>
> ### Resource Declaration:
>
> ## In /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/sample/recipes/default.rb
>
> 15: mysql_database "aws" do
>    16:   connection mysql_connection_info
>    17:   action :create
>    18: end
>    19:
>
> ### Compiled Resource:
>
> ## Declared in /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/sample/recipes/default.rb:15:in `from_file'
>
> mysql_database("aws") do
>     provider Chef::Provider::Database::Mysql
>     action [:create]
>     retries 0
>     retry_delay 2
>     guard_interpreter :default
>     database_name "aws"
>     cookbook_name :sample
>     recipe_name "default"
>     connection {:host=>"127.0.0.1", :username=>"root", :password=>"パスワード"}
>   end
>
> Running handlers:
>   [2015-02-15T08:20:08+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
>   Running handlers complete
>   [2015-02-15T08:20:08+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
>   [2015-02-15T08:20:08+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
>   Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.391575845 seconds
>   [2015-02-15T08:20:08+00:00] ERROR: mysql_database[aws] (sample::default line 15) had an error: LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2
>   [2015-02-15T08:20:08+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

---

【追記分】

### Berksfile

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"
cookbook "mysql2_chef_gem"
cookbook "database"
cookbook "yum"
```

### site-cookbooks/sample/metadata.rb

```
name             'sample'
maintainer       'YOUR_COMPANY_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures mysql'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'

depends 'mysql2_chef_gem'
depends 'database'
```

### site-cookbooks/sample/attributes/default.rb

```
default['mysql']['version']='5.5'
```

### site-cookbooks/sample/recipes/default.rb

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: mysql
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright 2014, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME
#
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#
mysql2_chef_gem 'default' do
  client_version node['mysql']['version'] if node['mysql']
  action :install
end

mysql_connection_info = { 
  :host     => '127.0.0.1',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => 'パスワード' 
}

mysql_database "aws" do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  action :create
end
```

### Aws側のLinuxのMysqlバージョン

```
Server version: 5.5.40 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

【エラー】

> Running Chef on aws_controller...
>   Checking Chef version...
>   Installing Berkshelf cookbooks to 'cookbooks'...
>   Resolving cookbook dependencies...
>   Using apt (2.6.1)
>   Using build-essential (2.1.3)
>   Using chef-sugar (2.5.0)
>   Using database (4.0.2)
>   Using mariadb (0.2.12)
>   Using mysql (6.0.13)
>   Using mysql2_chef_gem (1.0.1)
>   Using openssl (2.0.2)
>   Using postgresql (3.4.14)
>   Using rbac (1.0.2)
>   Using resource-control (0.1.1)
>   Using smf (2.2.1)
>   Using yum (3.5.2)
>   Using yum-epel (0.6.0)
>   Using yum-mysql-community (0.1.12)
>   Vendoring apt (2.6.1) to パス/cookbooks/apt
>   Vendoring build-essential (2.1.3) to パス/cookbooks/build-essential
>   Vendoring chef-sugar (2.5.0) to パス/cookbooks/chef-sugar
>   Vendoring database (4.0.2) to パス/cookbooks/database
>   Vendoring mariadb (0.2.12) to パス/cookbooks/mariadb
>   Vendoring mysql (6.0.13) to パス/cookbooks/mysql
>   Vendoring mysql2_chef_gem (1.0.1) to パス/cookbooks/mysql2_chef_gem
>   Vendoring openssl (2.0.2) to パス/cookbooks/openssl
>   Vendoring postgresql (3.4.14) to パス/cookbooks/postgresql
>   Vendoring rbac (1.0.2) to パス/cookbooks/rbac
>   Vendoring resource-control (0.1.1) to パス/cookbooks/resource-control
>   Vendoring smf (2.2.1) to パス/cookbooks/smf
>   Vendoring yum (3.5.2) to パス/cookbooks/yum
>   Vendoring yum-epel (0.6.0) to パス/cookbooks/yum-epel
>   Vendoring yum-mysql-community (0.1.12) to パス/cookbooks/yum-mysql-community
>   Uploading the kitchen...
>   Generating solo config...
>   Running Chef...
>   [2015-02-15T14:50:52+00:00] WARN:
>
> ---
>
> SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
>   encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
>   attacks.
>
> To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:
>
> ```
>    # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
>    ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer
>
> # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
>    verify_api_cert true
>   ```
>
> To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the
>   `knife ssl check` command like so:
>
> `knife ssl check -c /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/solo.rb`
>
> ---
>
> Starting Chef Client, version 11.16.4
>   Compiling Cookbooks...
>   Converging 2 resources
>   Recipe: sample::default
>    * mysql2_chef_gem[default] action install
>    Recipe: build-essential::_rhel
>      * package[autoconf] action install (up to date)
>      * package[bison] action install (up to date)
>      * package[flex] action install (up to date)
>      * package[gcc] action install (up to date)
>      * package[gcc-c++] action install (up to date)
>      * package[kernel-devel] action install (up to date)
>      * package[make] action install (up to date)
>      * package[m4] action install (up to date)
>      * package[patch] action install (up to date)
>      * mysql_client[default] action create
>
> ```
>  ================================================================================
>  Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_client[default]'
>  ================================================================================
>
>  NoMethodError
>  -------------
>  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
>
>  Cookbook Trace:
>  ---------------
>  /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:287:in `package_name_for'
>  /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:319:in `client_package'
>  /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:29:in `client_package_name'
>  /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb:19:in `block in <class:MysqlClient>'
>
>  Resource Declaration:
>  ---------------------
>  # In /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql2_chef_gem/libraries/provider_mysql2_chef_gem_mysql.rb
>
>   16:           mysql_client 'default' do
>   17:             version new_resource.client_version
>   18:             action :create
>   19:           end
>   20: 
>
>  Compiled Resource:
>  ------------------
>  # Declared in /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql2_chef_gem/libraries/provider_mysql2_chef_gem_mysql.rb:16:in `block in <class:Mysql>'
>
>  mysql_client("default") do
>    action [:create]
>    retries 0
>    retry_delay 2
>    guard_interpreter :default
>    cookbook_name :sample
>    version "5.5"
>  end
> ```
>
> ================================================================================
>      Error executing action `install` on resource 'mysql2_chef_gem[default]'
>      ================================================================================
>
> NoMethodError
>
> ---
>
> mysql_client[default] (/home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql2_chef_gem/libraries/provider_mysql2_chef_gem_mysql.rb line 16) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
>
> Cookbook Trace:
>
> ---
>
> /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:287:in `package_name_for'
>
>      /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:319:in`client_package'
>      /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:29:in `client_package_name'
>
>      /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb:19:in`block in '
>
> Resource Declaration:
>
> ---
>
> # In /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/sample/recipes/default.rb
>
> ```
>  9: mysql2_chef_gem 'default' do
> 10:   client_version node['mysql']['version'] if node['mysql']
> 11:   action :install
> 12: end
> 13:
> ```
>
> Compiled Resource:
>
> ---
>
> # Declared in /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/sample/recipes/default.rb:9:in `from_file'
>
> mysql2_chef_gem("default") do
>        action [:install]
>        retries 0
>        retry_delay 2
>        guard_interpreter :default
>        cookbook_name :sample
>        recipe_name "default"
>        client_version "5.5"
>        gem_version "0.3.17"
>      end
>
> Running handlers:
>   [2015-02-15T14:50:55+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
>   Running handlers complete
>   [2015-02-15T14:50:55+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
>   [2015-02-15T14:50:55+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
>   Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 3.096810316 seconds
>   [2015-02-15T14:50:55+00:00] ERROR: mysql2_chef_gem[default] (sample::default line 9) had an error: NoMethodError: mysql_client[default] (/home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql2_chef_gem/libraries/provider_mysql2_chef_gem_mysql.rb line 16) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
>   [2015-02-15T14:50:55+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

Comment: もしかするとこちら [Ruby 2.0 + MySQL + Windows: cannot load such file -- mysql2](http://www.oiax.jp/rails/zakkan/ruby_2_0_mysql_windows.html) が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
mysql2を再インストール等を行ってみたりしたのですが、同じエラーとなりました。インストールオプション等の観点からもなにか対応できないか引き続き調べて行きたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

下記の mysql.rb がなくなったのが原因かなと思われます。
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/v3.1.0/recipes/mysql.rb

sample/metadata.rb に、depends "mysql2_chef_gem" を付け加えて

sample/recipes/default.rb の最初に、mysql.rb と同じ内容の

mysql2_chef_gem 'default' do
  client_version node['mysql']['version'] if node['mysql']
  action :install
end

をおいてみてください。

Comment: コメント有り難う御座います。
mysqlが5.5だったため、attrbuteファイルにdefault['mysql']['version']='5.5'
として対応しましたが、エラーが発生しましたので、一部抜粋します。
Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_client[default]'
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
中略
[2015-02-15T14:17:11+00:00] ERROR: mysql2_chef_gem[default] (sample::default line 11) had an error: NoMethodError: mysql_client[default] (/home/ec2-user/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/mysql2_chef_gem/libraries/provider_mysql2_chef_gem_mysql.rb line 16) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: 少し、変化あったみたいですね。現象の再現ができればもう少しわかりそうです。再現用の cookbook があるといいのですが、

Comment: 続けてのコメント有り難う御座います。
site-cookbooks/sample/recipes/default.rb
-------------------------------------------------

mysql2_chef_gem 'default' do
  client_version node['mysql']['version'] if node['mysql']
  action :install
end

mysql_connection_info = {
  :host     => '127.0.0.1',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => 'パスワード'
}

mysql_database "aws" do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  action :create
end

上記、とりあえずcookbook 載せておきますが、再現すればよいのですが、、、

Comment: すみません、質問内容に追記できたんですね、、、